# Why does the showcard function run twice and why the total check of scores isnt breaking the loop

Tags: python-3.x

```
    import random

class Player:
    deck = ["A♣", "2♣", "3♣", "4♣", "5♣", "6♣", "7♣", "8♣", "9♣", "10♣", "J♣", "K♣", "Q♣", "A♦", "2♦", "3♦", "4♦", "5♦",
            "6♦", "7♦", "8♦", "9♦", "10♦", "J♦", "K♦", "Q♦", "A♥", "2♥", "3♥", "4♥", "5♥", "6♥", "7♥", "8♥", "9♥",
            "10♥", "J♥", "K♥", "Q♥", "A♠", "2♠", "3♠", "4♠", "5♠", "6♠", "7♠", "8♠", "9♠", "10♠", "J♠", "K♠", "Q♠"]

    total = 0
    run = True
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("Enter your name : ")
        self.Bet = inputs.bet(self)
        self.Aval = inputs.Aval(self)

class Dealer:
    deck = ["A♣", "2♣", "3♣", "4♣", "5♣", "6♣", "7♣", "8♣", "9♣", "10♣", "J♣", "K♣", "Q♣", "A♦", "2♦", "3♦", "4♦", "5♦",
            "6♦", "7♦", "8♦", "9♦", "10♦", "J♦", "K♦", "Q♦", "A♥", "2♥", "3♥", "4♥", "5♥", "6♥", "7♥", "8♥", "9♥",
            "10♥", "J♥", "K♥", "Q♥", "A♠", "2♠", "3♠", "4♠", "5♠", "6♠", "7♠", "8♠", "9♠", "10♠", "J♠", "K♠", "Q♠"]

    total = 0

class inputs:
    def bet(self):
        """
        takes in the bet from the user and stores it in the player class
        :return: output
        """
        self.bet = input("Enter the amount for your bet : ")
        output = self.bet
        if self.bet.isnumeric() == False:
            print("Use your monke brains and enter correct input")
            return inputs.bet(self)
        else:
            return int(output)
    def Aval(self):
        """
        Takes the value for ace and stores it in the player class
        :return: output
        """
        self.aval = input("Enter the value for ACE (1 or 10) : ")
        output = self.aval
        if self.aval.isnumeric() == False:
            print("Use your monke brains and enter correct input")
            inputs.Aval(self)
        elif self.aval.isnumeric() == True:
            if self.aval in ["1", "10"]:
                return int(output)
            else:
                print("I understand you suffer braincell deficiency but I need you to fire up those 2 braincells you have and enter the proper number")
                inputs.Aval(self)

    def valcalc(card):
        """
        takes the card for player.deck and returns the value of that card
        :return: card value
        """
        if card[0] in ("K", "Q", "J"):
            return 10
        elif card[0] == "A":
            return p.Aval
        else:
            return int(card[0])

    def showcard(self):
        """
        shows the card and adds the card to the total of player and of dealer too
        :return:
        """
        pcard = random.choice(Player.deck)
        dcard = random.choice(Dealer.deck)
        print("Your card is : ", pcard)
        print("Dealer's card is : ", dcard)
        Player.deck.remove(pcard)
        Dealer.deck.remove(dcard)
        p.total += inputs.valcalc(pcard)
        d.total += inputs.valcalc(dcard)
        print(p.total)

    def hitorstop(todo):
        if todo.lower() in ("hit" or "stop"):
            if todo.lower() == "hit":
                inputs.showcard(1)
            elif todo.lower() == "stop":
                pnum = 21 - p.total
                dnum = 21 - d.total
                if dnum > pnum:
                    print(Player.name, "wins")
                    Player.run = False
                    return Player.run
                elif pnum > dnum:
                    print("You lost against a dealer bot  , such a shame")
                    Player.run = False
                    return False
                else:
                    print("Its a tie , you didnt win shit , lol")
                    Player.run = False
                    return False
        else:
            inputs.hitorstop(input("\n\nDo you want to hit or stop : "))


p = Player()
d = Dealer()

while ((p.total or d.total) != 21) and (Player.run != False):
    inputs.showcard(1)
    if p.total == 21:
        print(p.name , "you lost")
        break
    elif d.total == 21:
        print(p.name , "you win")
        break

    inputs.hitorstop(todo = input("\nDo you want to hit or stop : "))
```

So what i am trying to do is make everything a function and if the input is wrong , the function runs again till correct input is being given

the inputs.showcard() function runs twice , the "stop" doesnt stop the inputs.hitorstop() and the player.total checks inside the loop arent working

Also is their any way to make the whole blackjack work better/efficiently?

Comment: function runs twice if ((p.total or d.total) != 21) and (Player.run != False) is validated.
The stop doesn't stop: no clue of what are you asking.
Checks aren't working: no clue of what are you asking

Comment: the player.total checks in the while loop at the very bottom of the code and in the function inputs.hitorstop() when it takes in "stop" in as input it must stop the whole thing and print the results of the blackjack game